# Codeigniter form validation callback not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to extend the validation class with my own function but it seems to skip the check.

**My code**

```
public function login_validation(){
 $this->load->library('form_validation');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean|callback_validate_credentails');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|md5');
    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        #redirect('home');
        //Just to check 
        echo "login success";
    }
    else{
        $this->load->view('view_login');
    }
}
```

My validate credentails function goes like this;

```
public function validate_credentials(){
   //loads model_user
   $this->load->model('model_users');
   //checks if login_validate function in model_users return true
    if($this->model_users->login_validate()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        //set validation message
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_credentails','Incorrect Username/Password');
        return false;
    }

}
```

My login_validate function in model_users if needed;

```
public function login_validate(){
    $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false; 
        }

}
```

This is the first time i've had this problem, am i doing something wrong? I've spent too much time on this :(

Comment: Check the file name is MY_form_validation.php and do you start the code like this "class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {" inside the file? Linux system is case sensitive with file names check it as well.

Comment: You mean the form_validation file in systems/libraries?

Comment: Why does it need changing tho?

Comment: Actually you were right, i needed to change the name and add some little function. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the solution. I needed to change the name of the `form_validation` class as Nish suggested and add this function.

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
    function run($module = '', $group = ''){
        is_object($module) AND $this->CI = &$module;
        return parent::run($group);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, I just wanted to add that the callback function should be a public function not private. I have wasted few minutes because of that.

Answer (score 2):

Your callback is `callback_validate_credentails` (tails) and your function name is `validate_credentials` (tials).  Typo maybe?

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo here, i spelt it correctly in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best advice is your LOGIN_validation check to be at your MODEL not at the form validation class... 
Its different THING !

Comment: I'm sending the form(in the view) to the function login_validation.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the `Callback_` function to the same controller it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

**For Codeigniter 3 form validation callback**
Just add `public $CI` in MY_Form_validation

path: application/libraries/MY_Form_validation

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    public $CI;
}
```

and then  on your controllers constructor:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->CI =& $this;
```

It's a HMVC related callback problem.
By this solution the current controller as the $CI variable to the form_validation library before assigning. This will allow your callback methods to function properly.